# infer template argument type from function return type

Tags: templates, d, type-inference

I expect this code to compile, but it doesn't.

```
ReturnType tryMe(ReturnType)() {
  static if (is(ReturnType == int)) {
    return 42;
  } else static if (is(ReturnType == string)) {
    return "Hello!";
  } else {
    assert(0);
  }
}

unittest {
  string r = tryMe();
  assert(r == "Hello!");
  int v = tryMe();
  assert (v == 42);
}
```

How to avoid this error message?

```
Error: template app.tryMe cannot deduce function from argument types !()(), candidates are:
       app.tryMe(ReturnType)()
```

If I 'refactor' my function so I return the result via a passed in reference, the code compiles. But it makes the function's api very ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unittest {
    auto r = tryMe!string();
    assert(r == "Hello!");
    auto v = tryMe!int();
    assert (v == 42);
}
```

Someone may correct me, but I think compiler cannot infer type from assignment.

Comment: You're right, type inference never takes the context of a call into account. The same is true for overloading: you can't overload on the return type, for example.